# Prove the following $R \subseteq A\times B$ and $S\subseteq B\times C \rightarrow $ $ S \circ R $ is symetric

Tags: relations, symmetry

I want to prove the following $ S \circ R $ is symetric, A,B,
C are sets

1. $R \subseteq A\times B$ is Symetric
2. $S\subseteq B\times C$ is Symetric

Any Suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, its from my test, I tried to figure out how I can do that and nothing. the question was "Prove the following". thanks

Answer (score 1):

Take $$R=\{(1,2),(2,1),(3,4),(4,3),(4,0),(0,4)\}\\ S=\{(3,2),(2,3),(3,0),(0,3),(1,4),(4,1)\}$$ so $$S\circ R=\{(1,3),(2,4),(3,1),(4,3),(4,2),(0,1)\}$$

Comment: Set $A = B = C = \{1,2,3\}$ and $R = \{(1,2), (2,1)\}$ and $S = \{(2,3), (3,2)\}$ are enough to show $S \circ R = \{(1,3)\}$ is not symmetric.